# Ordered List Map implementation in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I was wondering if there is a class out there that implements both the `Map` and `List` interfaces in Java.

I have a data structure that is primarily a `Map`. I map strings (IDs) to `Image`s. But in a specific part of my code, I need to present the user with all the available IDed `Images`. The only way to do that so far is to write this:

```
for (String id : myMap.keySet()) {
    // get the image like this "myMap.get(id)" 
}
```

So it would be nice to have a class that implements both `Map` and `List` so I could simply write:

```
for (Image img : myMap) {
  // the image is img
}
```

Does anyone know of such an implementation?

**EDIT**: After viewing the answers (which are all correct, voted up), I now realize I would also need the map to be sorted. When I say "sorted", all I mean is that I would like it to have the values in a specific order, one that I would be able to modify. I know this is not the original question, but I just realized that I need that.

**EDIT 2**: It seems I am indecisive. What I need is an ordered map, not a sorted one. Sorry for the confusion, people.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you need your items in a specific order, [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is your friend - it keeps items in insertion order. TreeMap will keep your items in an order defined by either a Comparator you give or a compareTo method of the key.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to change the item order though :(

Comment: I think, you can re-put item to the end of map by removing it and putting again.

Answer (score 19):

For an ordered Map, look at the [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).  That will keep your keys in the order of insertion.

If you use a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) it will keep the keys in sorted order. (The [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is the most common implementation.)

What you can use is `map.entrySet()`.  That will allow you to iterate over the Set of MapEntries.

Check out the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) for a bit more info.

Comment: thanks for the answer. please check out my edits as my question has slightly changed.

Comment: Thanks.  I usually prefer brevity over long-windedness.

Answer (score 8):

You've got already a bunch of practical answers. But answering directly the question...

> I was wandering if there is a class out there that implements both Map and List interfaces in Java.

... it's worth to mention that it's simply impossible. `remove(Object)` method is the obstacle.

In `Map` interface its signature is:

```
V remove(Object key);
```

And in `List` interface it's:

```
boolean remove(Object o);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [`Map.values()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) method, which returns a `Collection`.

Comment: nice answer. please check out my edits as my question has slightly changed.

Answer (score 2):

This gives you a collection of the stored values

```
myMap.values()
```

Comment: nice answer. please check out my edits as my question has slightly changed.

Comment: A HashMap will produce a value collection sorted by hash - which is usually not what you want. So go with jinguy's answer and use a TreeMap and then call values().

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (Image img : myMap.values()) {
    // the image is img
}
```

For sorted map look at [`java.util.SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementations. [`java.util.TreeMap`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is the most often choice. If you need just guaranteed iteration order you can try [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It offers iteration in the same order as you put elements to map. Or, optionally, in last-accessed order. If you'd like to move key (once added) to the end of map, you must explicitly remove it and put again.

Comment: nice answer. please check out my edits as my question has slightly changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [TreeMap](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) it is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time:

```
TreeMap<String, Image> mapByName = new TreeMap<String, Image>(new ByNameComparator());
```

where ByNameComparator() is a Comparator. Alternatively you can use the values() methond and sort using Collections.sort():

```
Collection<Image> images = mapByName.values();
Collections.sort(images, new BySizeComparator());
```