# How to Maintain order of insertion

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I want to add a key, value pair into a hashtable (or any other collection) but have to maintain insertion order. How can I do this?

Like I'll add 1 as key "one" as value, 2 as key and "two" as value.

The output should be:

```
1:one
2:two
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here are the characteristic differences of some important [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementations:

- [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):  "with predictable iteration order [...] which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*)."
- [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): "makes no guarantees as to the order of the map"
- [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html): "is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator`"

  - i.e. it's a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

So it looks like `LinkedHashMap` is what you need in this case.

Here's a snippet to illustrate the differences; it also shows a common way to iterate over all entries of a `Map`, and how using an interface to refer to objects allow great flexibility of choice of implementation.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        populateThenDump(new HashMap<String,Integer>());
        populateThenDump(new TreeMap<String,Integer>());
        populateThenDump(new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>());
    }
    static void populateThenDump(Map<String,Integer> map) {
        System.out.println(map.getClass().getName());

        map.put("Zero",  0);
        map.put("One",   1);
        map.put("Two",   2);
        map.put("Three", 3);
        map.put("Four",  4);

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above snippet is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ADouC)):

```
java.util.HashMap          // unordered, results may vary
Three => 3
Zero => 0
One => 1
Four => 4
Two => 2
java.util.TreeMap          // ordered by String keys lexicographically
Four => 4
One => 1
Three => 3
Two => 2
Zero => 0
java.util.LinkedHashMap    // insertion order
Zero => 0
One => 1
Two => 2
Three => 3
Four => 4
```

#### Related questions

- [Iterate Over Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-map)
- [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

  - If you want to modify the map while iterating, you'd need to use its [`Iterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

#### Similar questions

- [How to keep the order of elements in hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419708/how-to-keep-the-order-of-elements-in-hashtable)
- [Does entrySet() in a LinkedHashMap also guarantee order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190083/does-entryset-in-a-linkedhashmap-also-guarantee-order)
- [Java Class that implements Map and keeps insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order)
- [Ordered List Map implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212198/ordered-list-map-implementation-in-java)

Comment: Anybody else nervous about the doc's use of the world 'normally'? The excerpt "normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map" seems a little uncertain. Has anyone had any problems?

Answer (score 11):

For hash table, use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for adding link. I wanted to find javadocs for 1.6 on sun/oracle site, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for the `LinkedHashMap` class.