# Android - Get value from HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-widget

I have tried to search on HashMap in Android, but getting problem:

Consider this example:

```
HashMap<String, String> meMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put("Color1","Red");
meMap.put("Color2","Blue");
meMap.put("Color3","Green");
meMap.put("Color4","White");
```

now I want to iterate it and get the value of each color and want to display in "Toast".
how do I display it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @clamp ya i have already seen android-sdk

Comment: Maybe you should also read the available methods like `keySet()`, not just the descriptions.

Comment: @Pentium10 Dont know anything about HashMap....so by theory how can i come to know....btw thanx for help and support

Comment: The SDK contains descriptions about the methods it has, you should check and see what kind of methods can be run on HashMap prior to asking.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = meMap.keySet().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
    String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
    String value=(String)meMap.get(key);
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Key: "+key+" Value: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Note that iteration order is undefined. If you want the same order as the sets were added use LinkedHashMap

Comment: the above code is iterated over only on "key"..but not for "Value"..such as it displays only "color1", "color2"...etc. instead of "red", "blue", etc.

Comment: Just make a request to hashmap for the key and you will have it, I updated my code.

Comment: how to add LinkedHashMap to return in same order, help please.

Answer (score 93):

Here's a simple example to demonstrate `Map` usage:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Color1","Red");
map.put("Color2","Blue");
map.put("Color3","Green");
map.put("Color4","White");

System.out.println(map);
// {Color4=White, Color3=Green, Color1=Red, Color2=Blue}        

System.out.println(map.get("Color2")); // Blue

System.out.println(map.keySet());
// [Color4, Color3, Color1, Color2]

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
// Color4 -> White
// Color3 -> Green
// Color1 -> Red
// Color2 -> Blue
```

Note that the entries are iterated in arbitrary order. If you need a specific order, then you may consider e.g. `LinkedHashMap`

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
- [Java Tutorials/Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) - [The `Map` interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)
- [Java Language Guide/The for-each loop](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

#### Related questions

On iterating over entries:

- [Iterate Over Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-map)
- [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

  - If you want to modify the map while iterating, you'd need to use its [`Iterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

On different `Map` characteristics:

- [How to Maintain order of insertion using collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973751/how-to-maintain-order-of-insertion-using-collections)

---

#### On `enum`

You may want to consider using an `enum` and `EnumMap` instead of `Map<String,String>`.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Enums](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

#### Related questions

- [Enumerations: Why? When?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363120/enumerations-why-when/)

Comment: import java.util.*; must be added

Comment: If you only want the values, this answer is clearly more understandable

Answer (score 8):

This with no warnings!

```
    HashMap<String, String> meMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
    meMap.put("Color1","Red");
    meMap.put("Color2","Blue");
    meMap.put("Color3","Green");
    meMap.put("Color4","White");

    for (Object o : meMap.keySet()) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), meMap.get(o.toString()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
HashMap<String, String> meMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put("Color1", "Red");
meMap.put("Color2", "Blue");
meMap.put("Color3", "Green");
meMap.put("Color4", "White");

Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = meMap.values().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), myVeryOwnIterator.next(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Object key : meMap.keySet()) {
        String value=(String)meMap.get(key);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Key: "+key+" Value: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String, String> meMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put("Color1","Red");
meMap.put("Color2","Blue");
meMap.put("Color3","Green");
meMap.put("Color4","White");
Iterator iterator = meMap.keySet().iterator();
while( iterator. hasNext() ){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), meMap.get(iterator.next().toString()), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this work for me:

```
HashMap<String, String> meMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put("Color1","Red");
meMap.put("Color2","Blue");
meMap.put("Color3","Green");
meMap.put("Color4","White");

Iterator iterator = meMap.keySet().iterator();
while( iterator. hasNext() )
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), meMap.get(iterator.next().toString()), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you know Key, use this code

```
String value=meMap.get(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Iterator iterator = meMap.keySet().iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext() ){
                  //get key
                    String key=(String)iterator.next();
                    //toast value
                                           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+(String)meMap.get(key),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```