# how to insert screen coordinate into hashmap android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to insert screen coordinate into hashmap data structure means insert setX(x)and setY(y) value in hashmap. I make a android application in this application need to store screen coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Get size..

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/1298796)

And for Hash map

```
HashMap<Integer> meMap=new HashMap<Integer>();
meMap.put(width);
meMap.put(height);
```

Given is just an example. you can Do accordingly. Other [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422388/android-get-value-from-hashmap).

Comment: hee @Lucifer i have already accept this and implement this in my app