# how to get the data from Firebase into hash map?

Tags: java, android, firebase

How to get the latitude and longitude from `firebase` it stored like below screen shot

[image]

Comment: Refer This Link...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422388/android-get-value-from-hashmap

Comment: Refer this Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code for getting the values for lat and lng

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parkingSlots").child("compact").child("0").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.exists()) {
              try{
                float lng  =    Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
                 float lat  =    Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
            } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, if any possible way to get those values using model class?

Comment: use ModelClass modleClass =  dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelClass .java); Where your ModelClass  will have fields like longitude or latitude etc.